# Batch script that backup all pictures and videos but without one directory

Tags: loops, batch-file, for-loop

I have my script that allows me to backup pictures and videos in my whole computer. It's searching files using "for" loop but now I want it to skip some specific directories like "Windows" on C:\ or "AppData" in user directory. How I have to modify my script to achieve my goal?

```
SET FileSizeMov=1073741824
SET FileSizePic=20000

for %%d in (C:\ D:\ E:\ F:\) do (
    PUSHD %%d
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B/S/A *.mp4 *.mov *.wmv *.avi') do if %%~zF LSS %FileSizeMov% (xcopy /h /y /c "%%F" "%~d0\allVid\")
    for /f "delims=" %%F in ('Dir /B/S/A *.jpg *.jpeg') do if %%~zF GTR %FileSizePic% (xcopy /h /y /c "%%F" "%~d0\allPic\")
    POPD
)
```

Comment: What about using the `/EXCLUDE` option of [`xcopy`](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)?

Comment: Use `robocopy` with `/XD` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

extend the `dir`command with

```
^|findstr /i /v /g:filename
```

where *filename* contains the names of the directories to exclude in the format

> c:\directory to exclude\

The caret escapes the pipe so that the *dir* output is redirected to the `findstr` `/g:`specifies the filename for strings-to-match, `/i` means case-insensitive and `/v`means lines NOT including

(the extension forms part of the instruction to be executed, so it, too should be enclosed within the quotes)